# Медленная работа переходов между фрагментами в ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, google-maps, android-viewpager

У меня 5 Фрагментов в `ViewPager`. Инициализирую `ViewPager` в `MainActivity`:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    CalendarFragment scheduleFragment = new CalendarFragment();
    ServicesFragment servicesFragment = new ServicesFragment();
    ReviewsFragment reviewsFragment = new ReviewsFragment();
    NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(scheduleFragment);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(servicesFragment);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(reviewsFragment);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(notificationFragment);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(profileFragment);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

И в `ProfileFragment` работаю с `googleMaps`. Инициализирую в `onCreateView()`:

```
if (mMap == null) {
        final OnMapReadyCallback mapListener = this;
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            if (isAdded()) {
                mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(mapListener);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Пробовал инициализировать в `onViewCreated()` и в `onResume()`, результат одинаковый.

Так вот проблема в том, что когда из 5 пунктов меню нажимаю на 4, то он зависает на пол секунды. Так как при нажатии на 4-Фрагмент `NotificationFragment`, одновременно с ним создается и 5-фрагмент `ProfileFragment`, то есть срабатывают:

> ```
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onAttach()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onCreateView()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onViewCreated()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onResume()
> ```

Вопросы:

- возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на пункты меню, срабатывали только те методы, которые относятся к этому фрагменту на которую я нажал, а не инициализировались рядом находящие фрагменты вместе с ним?
- или пусть так, но цинициализация карты в `ProfileFragment` не задерживал основной поток?

**UPD:**

Проверив несколько вариантов с `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`, `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` и даже удалив инициализацию GoogleMaps во ProfileFragment выяснил что дело не в этом. Но после того как я удалил с `layout`:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

фрагмент начал открываться быстро. То есть задержка из за этого fragment в layout.xml. Но мне нужно работать с картой, поэтому удалить не могу)

Comment: а зачем эта задержка при инициализации карты?

Comment: Просто, и без этого тормозит, думал может это поможет, ну типа Fragment быстро создасться, а потом уже через секунду карта проинииализирутся

Comment: нет, такая задержка ничего не решит. Если вы нашли самостоятельное решение, оформите его в виде ответа, а не дополнения к вопросу.

Comment: Это не решение. Просто задержка из за layout. Ничего не поменялось.